# Can Ruby on Rails (Gems) controls web camera and mic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

For Ruby on Rails are there gems that allow users to control their own web cameras and mic so they can chat with somebody similar to skype? I know HTML5 has this ability, but are there gems that would make the coding a lot easier and faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using tokbox.com. Create an account, get an API key, and then use their gem `opentok`.

There used to be others, such as raydash.com, but that doesn't seem to be around anymore.

Another alternative would be to set up a flash media server, although I'm not certain how straightforward this would be.

Comment: It seems like a paid service. I have taken a look into the gems and found similar RTC web packages. At https://rubygems.org. I think I may explore more into it since I am very much new to ruby on rails. thanks